# auto-alias fields in query?

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

#### EDITED

I have two "problems" :

- pg-promise results are objects containing all the selected fields in lowercase
- in our company we have implemented a naming convention for the fields of the database

We do not want the server to return objects with the real fields name. I can rename them with the `receive` event like this :

```js
const initOptions = {
  receive(data, result, e) {
    // data = { myid: 1, tname: 'name' }
    refactorProperties(data);
    // data = { myId: 1, name: 'name' }
  }
};

const columnToJS = {
  "myid": "myId",
  "tname": "name",
  "anotherdatabasefieldname": "theJSObjectProperty",
};

function refactorProperties(data) {
  data.forEach(tmp => {
    for(const prop in tmp) {
      const newProp = columnToJS[prop];
      if(newProp) {
        tmp[newProp] = tmp[prop];
        delete tmp[prop];
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Here it is a very small object, but in practice it will be much bigger (join queries, etc.) The [doc](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:receive) specify that

> Any data pre-processing needs to be fast here, to avoid performance penalties.

**What is the limit ?
Do pg-promise have an helpers or something like this to done that with [Columns](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) ?**

```js
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
        { name: 'myid', prop: 'myId', cnd: true /* other options */ }
        { name: 'tname', prop: 'name' /* other options */ },
        { name: 'anotherdatabasefieldname', prop: 'theJSObjectProperty' /* other options */  },
      ], {
        table: 'mytable'
    });
const query = pgp.helpers.insert(obj, cs);
// query = "INSERT INTO "mytable"("tname","anotherdatabasefieldname") VALUES('nameValue','anotherValue')"

const query2 = pgp.helpers.insert(obj, cs, true); // third params = return values ?
// query2 = "INSERT INTO "mytable"("tname","anotherdatabasefieldname") VALUES('nameValue','anotherValue') RETURNING myid AS "myId", tname AS "name", anotherdatabasefieldname AS "theJSObjectProperty"

const query3 = pgp.helpers.select(obj, cs);
// query3 = "SELECT myid AS "myId", tname AS "name", anotherdatabasefieldname AS "theJSObjectProperty" FROM mytable where [...]"
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. Can you highlight the actual question? It is not clear what you want to `inverse`, while `without put aliases in each query`. The second part looks like you want to camelize it? The example looks inconsistent though to conclude.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it's more clear. By "inverse" I meant, since we can bind JS object property to a database field with [Column](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) is it possible to generate aliases in queries with it ?

Comment: pg-promise doesn't do any select aliasing, as it does not generate any `SELECT` statements at all.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace [helpers](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) in [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is there only to help you with generating multi-row inserts and updates in the same way as you would single-row ones. And that is it, nothing else. It was not designed to generate any `SELECT` statements, you have to do it yourself:

> It unifies the approach to generating multi-row `INSERT` / `UPDATE` queries with the single-row ones.

When it comes to aliasing a lot of columns, as well as complex SQL queries in general, you are supposed to keep all that inside external SQL files, just like [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo) shows it to you. With that structure, you can easily write SQL of any size and complexity, along with inline SQL documentation, and let [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) consume those and minify for fast execution.

As for camelizing columns, API for event [receive](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:receive) comes with example right there.

> What is the limit?

The limit is common sense, not a physical one. You are pre-processing all the data that arrives from the server within event [receive](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:receive), and you do not want it to take much time.